# Changing out a capacitor with a different tolerance

Tags: capacitor, guitar-pedal

I am trying to replace a capacitor in an already existing circuit. The original capacitor was 473k 100V capacitor, so it had a ±5 tolerance, but I am only able to find 473k 100V capacitors that have a ±10 tolerance.
Will this change anything within the circuit or should this be fine?

Comment: That's a mylar cap  - so It's an audio circuit.  I'm a player too and I work on tons of guitar gear semiprofessionally -- The most likely (if any) result of using a cap with a wider tolerance is a slight change in tone (i.e maybe very slightly brighter or darker).  Considering the length of time that's already passed, your ears are extremely unlikely to be able to discern this minimal effect.  Just replace it, if you find it unpleasant, get another cap and try again.   With respect (and very understandably) you're over analyzing this   ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the circuit and the actual tolerance of the replacement part. It might make a difference if it's (say) part of a tone control and happens to be way off value. If you have a capacitance meter, even an inexpensive one, you can check it.

It's more important in many cases that the capacitor be of the same type of dielectric and construction. Usually higher voltage rating is fine. It would be unusual that a capacitor that has important tolerance would fail by itself, because usually they are not very stressed. If it's not broken you shouldn't replace it, generally speaking.

Comment: It is part of a guitar pedal, but i was doing a mod and i accidentally cut off the leg, so i do need to replace it, but i have the 473k 100v as a replacement and i was not sure if the tolerance mattered or not. It is a mylar capacitor that i am replacing

Comment: It certainly won't hurt anything to try it, as long as the replacement is also polyester (Mylar) or other similar film type (polypropylene or polystyrene).